# Dispose HTTP response in .NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

I have a `.NET WebAPI` application and this is one of my api:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    ...building myResult here...

    var content = ElasticSearch.Json.ToJson(myResult);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

I get a `CA2000` error from code analisys:

> Error CA2000  In method 'GroupsController.Get(string, string, string,
>   bool, string)', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'response'
>   before all references to it are out of
>   scope

So I modified the code like this:

```
var content = ElasticSearch.Json.ToJson(myResult);
using (var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK))
{
    response.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

So far so good. No memory leaks and the code analyzer is happy again.
Unfortunately now one of my test is complaining that it cannot access anymore a disposed object. Here the test testing that api (just the final part):

```
// Assert
var httpResponseMessage = await result.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None);
var resultJson = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Assert.AreEqual(expectedJson, resultJson);
```

The `Assert()` is complaining that it cannot access an already disposed object, that is the actual api result:

> System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CheckDisposed()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()

How can I fix that? Disposing the object seems reasonable but at the same time the test should be able to access it

Comment: Can you make sure that httpResponseMessage contains successful response. In case of failed request everything will be disposed and in that case you have this issue. Just debug the test and see what you have in httpResponseMessage before the next line. That can be also helpful for use here to realize what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ApiController.OK

```
return Ok(myResult);
```

You should not use using (var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)) because ResponseMessageResult will hold reference to disposed HttpResponseMessage. That's the reason you get this error in assert.

To check, change your code to snippet below and add breakpoint on result. Check result.Response.disposed

```
 using (var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
            response.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            result = ResponseMessage(response);
        }

       // result.Response.disposed is true hence error in assert.
        return result;
```